# C#: How to Connect to Active Directory with SSL Enabled using DirectoryContext, Domains and DirectoryEntry classes?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I want to search all the Domains in a Forest and i do that in the following way:

```
foreach(Domain currDomain in Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains)
{
    try
    {
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new
                         DirectorySearcher(currDomain.GetDirectoryEntry());
        searcher.PageSize = 1000;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
        using (SearchResultCollection resList = searcher.FindAll())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to do the same with SSL Enabled. To do that i tried to set the

```
AuthenticationType
```

property in **DirectoryEntry** class to

```
AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer.
```

But, when i try  to execute, "An Operation Error Occured" exception is thrown.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Secure LDAP (LDAPS) listens on a different port (636) than regular LDAP (389). You need to tell it connect on that port. Try this:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new
                     DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + currDomain.Name + ":636");
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I got this working with help from [gabriel](/questions/tagged/gabriel)'s answer . Initially, i modified the code as given below with the help from the 1st answer:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + currDomain.Name + ":636")
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectoySearcher(searcher);
```

But still i got "An Operation Error Occured". Then i figured out, i have the following code as well:

```
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketLayer.
```

When i removed the above line, it started working fine and i confirmed it with WireShark.